# Scroll Top not working correctly in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have created a table where rows get populated dynamically. I have a add button where i can add rows as well. Here i want to show newly added row in the table at the bottom after i add an row,so i am using the below code is component.ts.

```
this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

But the above code doesn't seems to work properly. **The problem is that when i add a  new row,scroll is not completely going to the bottom of div tag, hence new row cannot be seen.**

Below is my html code where i am using a table inside a div tag as shown below.

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow-y:auto">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <th class="col-3">Q.No</th>
            <th class="col-4">Record Answer</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let answer of answerPaper; let i = index" class="d-flex">
            <td class="col-3">answer.no</td>
            <td class="col-4">answer.name</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button (click)="addrow()">Add Row</button>
```

Below is the component.ts

```
public addRow(){
    this.answerPaper.push({});
}
```

I am posting the image of scrollbar also.

[image: When i add a new row,scroll bar is not completely moving to the bottom of div hence newly added row is not seen completely]

**When i add a new row,scroll bar is not completely moving to the bottom of div hence newly added row is not seen completely**

Am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: use this `this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call your scroll to top or bottom once angular element is ready

```
  @ViewChild('scroll', { read: ElementRef }) public scroll: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.scrollBottom()
  }

  public scrollBottom() {
    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
```

[SLACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jy8s84?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.this is what i was looking for.

Comment: It's works for me, in my case, i needed scroll top only, and only works with this way, using native element.

Comment: What could  be doing wrong on my code, the method are executing with no problems but, no movement in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to scroll down on a comment list when a new comment is added.
But the logic is the same.
I define a variable `scrollDown: number;` and I recover the comment list like this:

```
@ViewChild('commentList') commentList: ElementRef;
```

Then, when the comment is added:

```
this.scrollDown = this.commentList.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

Finally, in the template:

```
<div #commentList class="document-comments-list" [scrollTop]="scrollDown">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Temp quick fix] Adding timer worked for me,

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  setTimeout(this.scrollBottom(), 500)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This solution worked for me.